# Vertex Class in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph

I am bad when it comes to templates in C++. My requirement is to make a template class called Vertex with a vector pair containing the child vertex number and edge type. This class would be a part of another templatized graph class which would do a DFS graph traversal with the help of Vertex Class.

I need some help in creating both the templatized classes... I am aware of the part further.

Comment: Why don't you try it first ? If you are not at ease with templates, it could be worth reading a book about C++ first. Since no one here will teach you templates in depth, and no one will bother writing code that you don't understand, I vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the [BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html).
Maybe you can use it instead of reinventing the wheel. If not look into the sources as a reference.

Comment: Here is the link to DFS implementation in BGL: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html